# Series solution of a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

Is the ODE

$(1-x^2)y''+y'+y=0$ solvable by simple power series (not Frobenius) method?
The reason I am asking this, is because if the eq were $(1-x^2)y''+xy'+y=0$, it could have been easy, since all the individual series could have been synched to $\sum A_nx^n$, i.e in terms of a single power series. 
Is there any workaround to it, without using the generalised method, i.e the Frobenius method?

Comment: It works in exactly the usual way.  Did you try it???

Comment: @David I tried both. The Frobenius looked promising.

Comment: @David do you mean the simple series method?

Comment: Simple method works fine.

Comment: @David https://imgur.com/a/FsU0u please check this out. If this is correct, please mention.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=t-1$ ,

Then $(1-(t-1)^2)y''+y'+y=0$

$(1-t^2+2t-1)y''+y'+y=0$

$(-t^2+2t)y''+y'+y=0$

$t(t-2)y''-y'-y=0$

Which is similar as the Gaussian hypergeometric ODE and can solve easily by Frobenius method